Autodesk Design Automation unable to register app bundle and activity with supported Revit engine?
We are using Autodesk's Design Automation for quite some time now. We were registering the AppBundle with the following Revit engine: engine: "Autodesk.Revit+2021" - however, recently when we executed the api request, we got the following error: "400 bad request, Failed to create an app bundle (invalid request)"
And the same happens with new "Activity" creation. Interestingly, if we try to use the Autodesk.Revit+2022(or 22+) engines, both requests are working properly.
In the documentation it says that the supported Revit engines are starting from 2018 all the way up to the latest 2024. Does anyone has an idea why 2021 is suddenly not working, or did I misunderstood the docs?

Revit 2021 engine was deprecated very recently on March 29, 2024. Sorry about that.

Please see engine deprecation date here. Also see announcement from last year.

I understand now, thanks. But still, the docs should be updated with such info as well, imo ;)

I shall let the right person know.
